# How to paste JSON data or import JSON file to firestore collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There simply has to be an option to upload, import, or paste JSON data for a firebase / firestore collection. I honestly can't believe that I have to ask this, but I have found some conflicting answers and nothing turns up on google.

Here is a pic of my admin page for the project, if that matters.

[image]

Comment: Firestore provides no data import mechanism (other than what it exports).  You're going to have to write code, or find some other utility for this.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Not sure how I can move large chunks of data from their current Postgres format to firebase.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to export from postgres, then write code to add to Firestore as needed.

Comment: The other issue is the postgres is likely storing SQL data and that's not directly compatible with NoSQL data stores. You're going to need to think through relationships and how objects interact. Then, write code to import your SQL data - possibly flat files if that's how they were exported and then 'convert' it to NoSQL thinking as collections and documents then write out the data. It's really important to go though the [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) to gain an understanding of NoSQL and how to read/write data. That will help structuring your data.

Comment: I understand all of the nuances of the collections and documents in firebase. I just thought that there would be a way to paste some JSON data into a collection.

Comment: Do you still have related questions about this?

Comment: Did the last comments help you?

Comment: I guess not. It isn't possible. Not sure how to mark a question about how to do what is impossible?

Comment: My question to you is if this is related to Firebase? I believe you can find answers in another place?

Comment: The answer is that what I was asking to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool on [Github](https://github.com/mduccc/firestore_json_import).

You can easy import your json file to firestore with command:

```
node app.js upload <colection/doc/colection2.col/doc> <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

- What you need firebase_admin_private_key
  [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#:%7E:text=To%20generate%20a%20private%20key,JSON%20file%20containing%20the%20key.)
- Also validate your json  before doing anything
  [here](https://jsonlint.com/)

> Here im looping to my jsonfile since it contains a list of json type

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const serviceAccount = require('/firebase_admin_private_key.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();

const data = require('json_file.json'); // Replace with your JSON file path

console.log(data)
for(const datax of data){
    db.collection('recipes') // Replace with desired collection name
  .add(datax)
  .then(ref => {
    console.log('Recipe uploaded successfully:', ref.id);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error uploading recipe:', err);
  });
}
```

1. Node setup
2. npm install firebase-admin